# Mongo won't run

Tags: server, 18.04, mongodb

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm trying to install mongodb. Prior to this I thought I made some errors so I went ahead and wiped everything to start over.

```
sudo service mongod stop 
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org* 
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb 
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

After that I went ahead and ran:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
sudo apt update
```

Then when I ran:

```
sudo apt install -y mongodb-org
```

Which generated the following console output:

[image: Console output]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

download mongodb community server

https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community

choose your os as ubuntu 18.04 and package as tar. download it and extract it. inside that directory there is a "bin" folder. you need to run mongod inside that folder. but before that you need to create a folder to store all the installation files. by default mongodb expects you to create "db" folder at the root of your hard drive. you can also create that folder anywhere you want but you need to tell mongodb that directory.
let's say you created mongo-data folder in desktop. get that directory with pwd command.

```
 /home/user/Desktop/mongodb-data
```

go inside the bin directory

```
 /home/username/Desktop/mongo/bin
```

run

```
  mongod --dbpath=/home/yilmaz/Desktop/mongodb-data
```

this will install mongodb after finishing installation it will not terminate. server will be running for connections

if you choose this method each time you run mongod from any directory you have to specify the dbpath

```
 mongod --dbpath=/home/yilmaz/Desktop/mongodb-data
```

if you create the db folder in the root directory you just run

```
  mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get mongodb by creating a docker-compose.yml file and add it as a service. This will pull the mongodb image from the docker registry. You can then visualize your database using robo3t